# Parsing XML Response from SOAP API

Tags: javascript, xml, soap, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am using the suds.js library in Appcelerator to interact with a SOAP API. I've successfully sent a request and am looking for help parsing the response. I'd like to parse out the location name.

http://pastie.org/private/rqekjes8qwlzwypw100vwa

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about suds.js, but jQuery can parse your xml fairly easily.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UprDs/1/

JS

```
var myXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Response>    <Data>        <MobileDropDetail>            <MobileDropTypeCode>Test</MobileDropTypeCode>            <MobileDropID>1</MobileDropID>        </MobileDropDetail>        <Locations>            <L>                <ID>1376</ID>                <Name>Testing Location</Name>            </L>            <L>                <ID>1403</ID>                <Name>Other Testing Location</Name>            </L>            <L>                <ID>1471</ID>                <Name>New Testing Location</Name>            </L>            <L>                <ID>1475</ID>                <Name>Test Los Angeles</Name>            </L>        </Locations>        <Groups>            <G>                <ID>251</ID>                <Name>Mobile Test Region</Name>            </G>            <G>                <ID>252</ID>                <Name>Mobile Demo Region</Name>            </G>        </Groups>        <LocationGroupPairs>            <LG>                <LID>1376</LID>                <GID>251</GID>            </LG>            <LG>                <LID>1475</LID>                <GID>251</GID>            </LG>            <LG>                <LID>1403</LID>                <GID>252</GID>            </LG>            <LG>                <LID>1471</LID>                <GID>252</GID>            </LG>        </LocationGroupPairs>    </Data>    <Error>        <Message>Success</Message>        <ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>    </Error></Response>';

alert($(myXML).find('Locations Name:eq(0)').html());​
```

Comment: Yeah, jQuery generally isn't used with Appcelerator. Suds.js is just a library to interact with the API. I was hoping somebody here just had some better skills at parsing XML than I.

Comment: Xpath is your friend (query: //Locations/L/Name). Maybe you should be more concrete regarding the framework/technology, you want to use for the parsing.